# Firebase v9 loads a large iframe.js (263K) on mobile

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js, angularfire

After upgrading Firebase from V8 to V9, on mobile version only, there is an IFRAME loading a huge javascript file (**263K**) from **https://[Firebase projectId].firebaseapp.com/__/auth/iframe.js** (See image below):

[image]

The only clue I've found so far is that it could be related to third-party cookies restrictions in chrome as mentioned in this forum: https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/TC1xTPG85EI.

I'm not using any cookie restrictions in Chrome since all cookies are allowed based on settings here: `chrome://settings/cookies?search=cookies`

Also, I have disabled **Safe Browsing Enhanced protection** and set it to **No protection (not recommended)** here: `chrome://settings/security?search=cookies`

but iframe.js is still being loaded in mobile mode.

I am using **firebase@9.0.0-beta.8** library with version 9 modular (not compat) code snippets here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade.

Any idea or clue about getting rid of this huge iframe.js file will be appreciated. Even though the library is BETA, everything else works as expected with tree-shaking that considerably reduced client side package size.

You can test with Lighthouse on my personal Website here:
https://guydumais.digital

Thanks in advance, see You!

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/L7XLEann3W4, where it might get more response.

Comment: Are you probably using react-firebase-hooks?

Comment: No @DavidGregorian,I'm using the native firebase hook in my authentication component like this: 
 

 **`import useFirebaseAuth from '@lib/hooks/useFirebaseAuth'`**
 

In my **package.json** I'm only using 2 packages:
1) **`"firebase": "9.0.0-beta.8",`**
2) **`"firebase-admin": "^9.11.0",`**

Comment: I am using  "@angular/fire": "^7.0.4" and "firebase": "^9.0.2" and getting same issues in my ionic-angular PWA. my app have only modular implementation.

Answer (score 3):

We also had this problem for quite a while, I've just recently found this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-dependencies

> On mobile browsers, the library will automatically open an iframe to your Auth domain preemptively. This is done to make the experience seamless for most users, but it can impact performance by loading additional code right when the app starts. This behavior can be avoided by utilizing initializeAuth() and manually passing the browserPopupRedirectResolver dependency to the functions that need it

```
import {initializeAuth, browserLocalPersistence, browserPopupRedirectResolver, indexedDBLocalPersistence, signInWithRedirect, GoogleAuthProvider} from "firebase/auth";
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";

const app = initializeApp({/** Your app config */});
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: [indexedDBLocalPersistence, browserLocalPersistence],
});

// Later
signInWithRedirect(auth, new GoogleAuthProvider(), browserPopupRedirectResolver);
```

Comment: With @angular/fire 7.5.0 and firebase 9.15.0, delaying browserPopupRedirectResolver (i.e. not providing it at init) causes: 
Class constructor BrowserPopupRedirectResolver cannot be invoked without 'new' :(

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my solution. I only dynamic [import](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports) firebase auth when I need it. So I don't call it in the entire application, only when am making request to firebase.
If you have small to medium application, it should not be to much work.
**Tip**: To keep the state of current user, use cookies.

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
  const { getAuth } = await import("firebase/auth");
  getAuth(firebase);
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me example how to import it dynamically?

Comment: check this out https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports

Comment: Dynamic import is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the option to use sign in with redirect / popup, the solution is as follows. In your main firebase config, overwrite the getter that determines whether or not the auth/iframe.js file should load.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { browserPopupRedirectResolver } from "firebase/auth";

Object.defineProperty(browserPopupRedirectResolver.prototype,
  '_shouldInitProactively', { get: function() {return false;} });

const firebaseConfig = { /*...*/ };
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

When needed later, call the following function from somewhere that will load just as the user sees the sign in with popup / redirect button, perhaps in a render method. The key call is to the redirect resolver initialize function.

```
const auth = getAuth();
let resolverIsInitialized = false;


async function initializePopupRedirectResolverOnRender() {
  if (resolverIsInitialized) return;

  try {
    await auth.authStateReady();
    if (!resolverIsInitialized) auth._popupRedirectResolver._initialize(auth);
    resolverIsInitialized = true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Reference to my solution on GitHub:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4946#issuecomment-1918193756